# Converting string type date values to date format in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, type-conversion, multiple-columns

Using Spark 3.1, I am trying to convert string type value ("MM/dd/yyyy") in into date
format ("dd-MM-yyyy"). There is a total of 5 date columns in my file and I want to change them into proper date format ("dd-MM-yy") from ("MM/dd/yy").
There are some values in these columns which are already in date format like 05-02-2022 ("dd-MM-YYYY") and some values in 10/23/2021 ("MM-dd-yyyy") format. I want to convert only those values which are in "MM-dd-YYYY" format to "dd-MM-yyyy" format. How can I achieve this?

Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[10/23/2019, 09/13/2021], [06/16/2020, 03/16/2021], [09/06/2022, 12/23/2019], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Output will be like 23-10-2019, 13-09-2021

My code:

```py
df = df.withColumn('date_col', to_date('Date_col', 'dd-MM-yy'))
```

The code is running fine, but it's returning undefined in output for date column. As I have 5 date columns, is it possible to do it using a `for` loop?

Comment: Hi @DerekO my df looks like  suppose i have one date column in my dataframe which have value as 10/21/2022 in excel when i am seeing this it is shown as general not as date..i want to change this value into dd-mm-yyyy format (21-10-2022)

Comment: can you include a sample of your dataframe as formatted text? there are some good examples of how to best do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Note - spark's default date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` which is of DateType(). all other formats are strings for spark. looking at the sample, your source format seems to be `MM/dd/yyyy`. `to_date` will parse the string based on the provided source format and return the default formatted DateType() result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example input df (all the columns are of the *string* date type):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('x', '01/31/2021', '12/31/2020'),
     ('y', '1/1/2020', '1/18/2020'),
     ('z', '15-01-2020', '20-10-2020')],
    ['id', 'c1', 'c2'])
```

The following will convert every column into *date* type:

```py
for c in ['c1', 'c2']:
    df = df.withColumn(
        c, 
        F.when(F.col(c).rlike('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'), F.to_date(c, 'M/d/yyyy'))
         .when(F.col(c).rlike('\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}'), F.to_date(c, 'd-M-yyyy'))
    )

df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+
# | id|        c1|        c2|
# +---+----------+----------+
# |  x|2021-01-31|2020-12-31|
# |  y|2020-01-01|2020-01-18|
# |  z|2020-01-15|2020-10-20|
# +---+----------+----------+
```

`rlike` method checks if the string conforms to the specific regex pattern, and if it does, `when` condition applies a function.
`\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}` checks the format `M/d/yyyy`
`\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}` checks the format `d-M-yyyy`
If you have some other format, you will get *null*. To not get null, you would need to include that other format into this function too.

Spark does not support *date* types formatted in some other way except for `yyyy-MM-dd`. If you need another format, you will need to again convert the *date* type into *string* type, but with the format which you need:

```py
for c in ['c1', 'c2']:
    df = df.withColumn(
        c, 
        F.date_format(
            F.when(F.col(c).rlike('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'), F.to_date(c, 'M/d/yyyy'))
             .when(F.col(c).rlike('\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}'), F.to_date(c, 'd-M-yyyy')),
            "dd-MM-yyyy"
        )
    )

df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+
# | id|        c1|        c2|
# +---+----------+----------+
# |  x|31-01-2021|31-12-2020|
# |  y|01-01-2020|18-01-2020|
# |  z|15-01-2020|20-10-2020|
# +---+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

to_date changes a column to date type, so you need to specify the format your string is in but not the target format.
You should use date_format function which finally change the date column to another string of another format.

> Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format
> specified by the date format given by the second argument.

```
df.select(date_format(to_date(df.t, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy").alias('date')).show()
```

If you only have 5 columns to change to the date type and this number will not change dynamically, I suggest you just do:

```
df.withColumn("col1", date_format(to_date("dt1", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
.withColumn("col2", date_format(to_date("dt2", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
.withColumn("col3", date_format(to_date("dt3", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
.withColumn("col4", date_format(to_date("dt4", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
.withColumn("col5", date_format(to_date("dt5", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Hi @Young what is 'dt' defining in your code

Comment: Is it  creating a new column because i dont want to create a new column i already have those

Comment: it is the column of date in your origin format.

Comment: if you want to replace the old column: df.withColumn("Date_col", date_format(to_date("Date_col", MM/dd/yyyy'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents

1. Created a data frame with 2 columns(You can create as many columns as you need)

   ```
    df = spark.createDataFrame([('05/22/2022','10/21/2022')],schema=['Date_col1','Date_col2'])
   ```
2. Use the to_date() followed by date_format()

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    df1 = df.withColumn('date_col1',date_format(to_date(col("Date_col1"),"MM/dd/yyyy"),'dd-MM-yyyy'))\
            .withColumn('date_col2',date_format(to_date(col("Date_col2"),"MM/dd/yyyy"),'dd-MM-yyyy'))\
   ```
3. Print the data frame

   ```
    df1.show()
   ```

Please check the below image:

[image]